# Picture element in HTML use always the first srcset element

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I'm implementing responsive images on an HTML page.

This is the picture element with srcset

```
​<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" 
  srcset="images/emily-600px.webp 600w, images/emily-550px.webp 550w, images/emily-460px.webp 460w, images/emily-340px.webp 340w,images/emily-250px.webp 250w" 
  sizes="600px, (min-width: 75rem) 550px, (min-width: 62rem) 460px, (min-width: 48rem) 340px, (min-width: 36rem) 250px">
  <source type="image/jpeg" 
  srcset="images/emily-600px.jpeg 600w, images/emily-550px.jpeg 550w, images/emily-460px.jpeg 460w, images/emily-340px.jpeg 340w,images/emily-250px.jpeg 250w" 
  sizes="600px, (min-width: 75rem) 550px, (min-width: 62rem) 460px, (min-width: 48rem) 340px, (min-width: 36rem) 250px">
  <img src="images/emily.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="EMILY .....">
</picture>
```

I'm using bootstrap and even if I resize my Chrome browser windows it always uses emily-600px.web as a source for the image. For example, if the browser is resized to 800px, the image is rendered at 336px width but it continues to use the emily-600px.webp instead of using emily-340px.webp

What am I missing?

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using src-set, just use the aspect-ratio property and object-fit property.

```css
.image{
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     object-fit: cover;
     aspect-ratio: 16/9; /*Also you can use 1/1, 1/5 etc...*/
}
```